# Cmake-gui with new cmake

Tags: 12.04, package-management, dependencies, cmake

I installed Cmake 3.5 and I want to use cmake-gui with it, as I was used to before.  But what was installed is only cmake itself. Any chance getting a GUI with it?

Comment: Have you installed `cmake-qt-gui`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425599/where-is-the-cmake-gui-for-linux

Comment: @Melebius thanks for asking. `cmake-qt-gui` depends on cmake 2.8, so I am trying to make it work for 3.5. Maybe this is not possible at all? If so, maybe there is other GUI I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cmake code for Linux comes with `cmake-gui`, but it is not built by default. One can open `bootstrap` file, scroll down and set:

```
cmake_bootstrap_qt_gui="1"
```

After that run `bootstrap`, `make` and `make install` again.